# Transform object keys and properties into an array

Tags: javascript

```
function objectToArray(obj) {
  var newArr = [];
  var myKeys = Object.keys(obj);
  var myValues = Object.values(obj);

  for(var i=0; i<myKeys.length; i++) {
    newArr.push(myKeys[i]);
  }
  return newArr;
}

objectToArray({
  D: 1,
  B: 2,
  C: 3
});
  

// Should output  [["D", 1], ["B", 2], ["C", 3]]
```

Hello, Trying to put the values for each of these arrays in as specified. I keeping getting ['D1'] instead of ['D', 1]. Any idea how to place these values correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You have to push an array, like this: `[myKeys[i], myValues[i]]`

```js
function objectToArray(obj) {
  var newArr = [];
  var myKeys = Object.keys(obj);
  var myValues = Object.values(obj);

  for (var i = 0; i < myKeys.length; i++) {
    newArr.push([myKeys[i], myValues[i]]);
  }
  return newArr;
}

const result = objectToArray({
  D: 1,
  B: 2,
  C: 3,
});

console.log(result); // [["D", 1], ["B", 2], ["C", 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Manas Khandelwal, you could get the value directly from the obj if you have the key, so this is how I would do it:

```js
function objectToArray(obj) {
  var newArr = [];
  for (let key in obj) {
        newArr.push([key, obj[key]]);
  }
  return newArr;
}

const result = objectToArray({
  D: 1,
  B: 2,
  C: 3,
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: If you're going to recommend `for...in` you need to also provide the appropriate checks for `ownProperty` as otherwise it will iterate all enumerable properties that are keyed by strings including inherited enumerable properties. see: [`for...in: Iterating over own properties only`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#iterating_own_properties)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for Object.entries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries. This function does exactly what you are looking for.